# Selenium Grid Hub with node(s) set up. Whats next? (Picture included)

Tags: webdriver, selenium-grid, automated-tests

I am using Selenium 2 and I have the grid hub currently set up.  I have a local node in place.

[image: what my hub looks like]

This is what my hub looks like.

I want to load the same webpage on a number of these browsers.

Is it time for me to start writing the webdriver code?(using c# on VS?)

Answer (score 0):

I can only provide you some java code, but C# should be quite similar.

```
String gridconfig = "your grid url";    
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(this.gridconfig), capabilities);

//Do your test stuff with driver
```