# What is my next step after Selenium grid hub & nodes have been set up?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-grid

I have a Selenium Grid hub version 2.22.0 set up with 5 nodes running.  Here the list of them:

- 1 Local node running windows 7(my machine)
- 1 Virtual machine running Windows XP
- 1 Virtual machine running Windows Vista
- 2 Virtual machines running Windows 7

I want to be able to send jobs to those machines that will load a specific browser(s) and use webdriver to drive commands through them.

I need to do It using Visual Studio with C# language.
(Also, I booted the grid and all of the nodes using ***Java*** standalone servers, does that mean my webdriver will need to be written in ***Java*** also?)

If you know of any **current** tutorials using webdriver and grid that would be great. (all the tutorials I can find use selenium grid version 1)

Comment: I would also like to use Nunit as my testing framework.

Comment: Take a look at my Answer to [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035802/selenium-grid-hub-with-nodes-set-up-whats-next-picture-included) maybe it helps you.

Your webdriver tests don't have to be written in Java, you can also use C# or Nunit

Comment: I appreciate that Volk.  However, that answer is somewhat shallow and I am in no way an experienced coder.  Thanks though.

Comment: Like I'm not sure how to call which node or which .dll references to use

Comment: Ok that's a bit of a Problem, you have to write some code. I would first do some simple Nunit tutorials. And when you get familiar with coding and running Nunit tests, add some Webdriver stuff to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are Java specific commands are to initiate Grid and register the Nodes. It has nothing to do with Scripts.

You can write scripts in your preferred Language (C#,Java..etc).

Here are some pages which gives more information on how to write Selenium code in C# and how to use Grid.

http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/tutorials/selenium/selenium_two_csharp_nunit.htm
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2

I hope this helps you ...All the best :)

Answer (score 0):

When you start your nodes you give them something like

```
-browser "-browserName=internetexplorer,version=9,platform=windows"
```

When you write your tests you can use this node with the following code:

```
String gridconfig = "your grid url";    
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities("internetexplorer", "9", Platform.WINDOWS);
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(this.gridconfig), capabilities);
//Do your test stuff with driver
```